# Read from a file that contains both int and string using bufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

so i am trying to read a file that contains both an int and  a string. And so the main goal is for the user to enter a reference number and the program to spit out the line below. I am trying to use a linear search algo, here is the file:

```
 1<---Reference #
 The Adventures of Tom Sawyer<---Line to Spit out
 2
 Huckleberry Finn
 4
 The Sword in the Stone
 6
 Stuart Little
 10
 Treasure Island
 12
 The Secret Garden
 14
 Alice's Adventures in Wonderland
 20
 Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea
 24
 Peter Pan
 26
 Charlotte's Web
 31
 A Little Princess
 32
 Little Women
 33
 Black Beauty
 35
 The Merry Adventures of Robin Hood
 40
 Robinson Crusoe
 46
 Anne of Green Gables
 50
 Little House in the Big Woods
 52
 Swiss Family Robinson
 54
 The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe
 56
 Heidi
 66
 A Winkle in Time
 100
 Mary Poppins
```

Here is the code i currently have:

```
   public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   ArrayList<Integer> colours = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   BufferedReader br = null;
/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    int word=0;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Booklist.txt"));

        while ((word == br.read())){
            colours.add(word);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    initComponents();
}

static public Boolean linearSearch(ArrayList colours, String B) {
    for (int k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {
        if (A[k].equals(B)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For starters if you could help me at least read the file properly that'd be great.

Comment: Why use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`?

Comment: If you're using [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), why not use the very handy [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) method it provides for your convenience? --- Also, are you aware that the [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) method you are calling just returns one **character** at a time? It doesn't read multiple digits and return the number they represent.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use a Map.

```
Map<Integer,String> readFileasMap(String file) throws IOException{
    Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
        String text = br.readLine();
        map.put(number, text);
    }
    br.close();
    return map;
}
```

Then you can return the appropriate line with `map.get(index)`.
If you want to keep it with lists the function is very similar.

```
List<Integer> indexes;
List<String> titles;
void readFileasLists(String file) throws IOException{
    indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    titles = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
        String text = br.readLine();
        indexes.add(number);
        titles.add(text);
    }
    br.close();
    return;
}
```